# Assembly: What is the difference between a conditional branch and a conditional jump?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I read at https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/labmanual/assembly.html that there are **conditional jump** instructions such as

`JE`, `JNE`, `JG`, etc.

But they also talk about **conditional branch**es. What is the difference between these terms, or are they synonyms?

Is every conditional jump a conditional branch and vice versa?

Comment: Branches and jumps are the same thing. Though if they're conditional and short range, like the Jcc instructions were all originally in the 8086 instruction set, they're more likely to be called branches.

Comment: But couldn't there be conditional branches due to other instructions than jumps, e.g. calls or rets?

Comment: The CALL and RET instructions aren't conditional and aren't considered either a branch or a jump. They're part of a larger group of instructions call control transfer instructions that include branches/jumps.

Comment: I see, so are there conditional control transfer instructions other than conditional jumps?

Comment: The other conditional control transfer instructions are LOOP, LOOPE and LOOPNE. These are basically specialized conditional branches that also decrement the ECX register. The INTO and BOUND instructions are also technically conditional control transfer instructions, they cause software interrupts when a condition is met, but they're never used in modern x86 programming.

Comment: If you transform your comments into an answer, I can accept and upvote it.

Comment: Yes - it's interesting that many books on x86, x86-64 have sections called branching although the specific mnemonic instructions are JuMP instructions; conditional or otherwise. ARM has mnemonic instructions that are called b(ranch); e.g., bl bge bne beq... It's kind of like the Intel Architecture manuals that use the AT&T syntax vs the Intel syntax.

Comment: In some processors like the 6502 family, branches are relative and jumps are absolute. i.e. branches transfer control a number of bytes relative to the program counter and jumps transfer control to an absolute address.

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_(computer_science)): *"Machine level branch instructions are sometimes called jump instructions. Machine level jump instructions typically have unconditional and conditional forms where the latter may be taken or not taken depending on some condition."*